# ¿Como puedo mover las palabras y la imagen en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Estoy aprendiendo lenguaje de programación php con base de datos y MySQL pero no puedo mover una imagen hacia la derecha y 3 palabras hacia la izquierda (están invertidas, osea imagen izquierda y palabras derecha) y ya no tengo ni idea de que hacer ¿Pueden ayudarme? Logre cambiar de lugar las palabras pero al momento de intentarlo con la imagen, las palabras se mueven junto a la imagen, quisiera saber que etiqueta usar para hacer esta operación y que no hacer al momento de colocarlo.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Experto HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="encabezado">   
    <div class="centrar">

        <img src="img/logo.png">

        <ul class="opciones">

            <li class="opcion">Nosotros</li>
            <li class="opcion">Servicios</li>
            <li class="opcion">Contactanos</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
margin: 0; /*margen 0*/     
padding: 0; /*espaciado 0*/
}
#encabezado{
    width: 100%; /*anchura*/
    background-color: #000;

}
.centrar{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.opciones{
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;   
}
.opcion{
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    border-left: #fff solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: Estás hablando de maquetar esos elementos en una página web?

Comment: Exactamente, en una pagina web en un host local (si no me equivoco, así es).

Comment: Como vamos a ayudar si no tenemos código, nisiquiera sabemos que es lo que estás realizado, puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar tu código y explicar con detalle lo que quieres realizar.

Comment: Agrega el código mínimo necesario para ayudarte entonces por favor

Comment: Soy muy nuevo en esto y en la pagina, no sean tan duros.

Comment: Yo te invite (por favor) a qué agregues tu código amigo :) y eso es para que podamos auxiliarte

Comment: puede ser que hables de un div con float left?

Comment: Si, lo que menciono ilernet, aunque ya edite mi pregunta y agregue los códigos que les puede servir para ver cual es el problema sobre mi pregunta o que tengo que hacer.